# How to switch screens using React Navigation Drawer

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have the following navigation structure:

- App Navigator (switch navigator)

  - Auth Screens (stack navigator)
  - Home (tab navigator)

    - Feed
    - Others
    - Profile (contains drawer)
  - Settings, Legal info etc.

Example Drawer contents

- Settings (navigates to screen out of tab navigator)
- Notifications & Sound

How would I add the labels of and navigate to 'Settings, Legal info' through the drawer?
Extra: 'Profile' label shouldn't show on the drawer.

A similar example is the Instagram drawer in the profile tab. When you chose an option it pushes a new screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you need is navigation actions. If you know Redux you know how it works. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html

Comment: Redux is pretty overkill considering my project size. Any other way?

Comment: You don't need to implement redux. Navigation actions use redux under the hood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with clunky yet working solution.

Drawer navigation routes

```
`...
// To hide a specific route (Profile)
HiddenLabel:{
    screen:ScreenA,
    navOptions:{
        drawerLabel:()=>null
    }
}
A:{
    screen:()=>null
    navOptions:{
        drawerLabel:'Settings'
    }
}
...`
```

Drawer navigation custom component

```
`
...
contentComponent:(props)=>(
    // Should be wrapped in SafeAreaView
    <DrawerItems {...props} onItemPress={
        ({route})=>{
            // query and use props.navigation to navigate to route.routeName
        }
    }/>
)
...
`
```

And that's pretty much it. If you have another solution please do post it.